# Restrict access to IP with htaccess

Tags: apache, authentication, mod-rewrite, authorization

i need restrict access to all except some ip, i place into .htaccess this lines:

```
Require all denied
Require ip 1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2
```

In this case, the access is denied for all, i f i use:

```
Require all granted
Require ip 1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2
```

All can access to directory.

`AllowOverride` directive is set to `All`, `mod_rewrite` is installed and mod_authz is loaded, apache 2.4 installed into ubuntu server, any ideas?

UPDATE

I have tried also with

```
Require all denied
Require ip 1.1.1.1 
Require ip 2.2.2.2
```

But nothing...

Answer (score 0):

You need only one directive

```
Require not ip 1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2
```

It allow access only to all hosts except `1.1.1.1` and `2.2.2.2` ip's

Comment: Not work, in this way, all access is denied, like `Require all denied`

Comment: @hellb0y77I changed my answer to meet your requirement (my misunderstanding)

Comment: I need to do the opposite , but a few can access

Comment: My previous answer do that :\